# Quick question on manipulating native arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <iostream>

int
main(void)
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int x[n];

    return 0;
}
```

From C point of view, the above code should not be compiled properly because the size of the array 'x' has not been defined yet, I suppose.

Only after an user passes an argument for the variable 'n', the size of 'x' can be defined, yet the code did not crash while compiling and running and I wonder why.

If it was written in C, I think people would have used malloc for run-time configurable arrays.

Maybe I have some misconception on arrays, memory allocation, compiler and the relationship between c and c++. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually, dynamic arrays is perfectly valid. Your compiler is probably compiling by default in C99 mode which allows dynamic arrays like these to be allocated on stack. It uses `alloca()` behind the scenes.

Comment: `int x[n];` is not valid in standard `c++`. Instead use `std::vector`

Comment: `relationship between c and c++` think of them as 2 different languages and you will be better off.

Comment: @drescherjm, But the code did run without any issues. I checked the sizeof 'x' is dynamically changing as per the given argument.

Comment: Enable all warnings. Some compilers allow the nonstandard VLA extension but will warn about non-compliant code.

Comment: Both g++ and clang++ support variable sized arrays as extension. Try adding `-pedantic` to get a warning about it and `-pedantic-errors` to make it not compile, as would be the case with standard C++.

Comment: Why don't you try inputting a negative number or a very large number and see how you get on with this VLA extension?

Answer (score 7):

No, from a C point of view the code is invalid because `<iostream>` is not a C header and `std::cin` is a syntax error. On the other hand, the `int x[n];` part would be fine: It's a variable-length array, a feature first introduced in C99.

Standard C++ has no variable-length (native) arrays. g++ [allows them as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), though:

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++.

Normally, in C++, you'd use `std::vector`.